# Basic addition of program in shell

Tags: shell

we have written a simple shell script

```
cd location\address

var1='grep -w -c exception server.log
var2='grep -w -c exception server.log.1

var3= $var1 + $var2

echo $var3
echo $var3
echo 'addition of exception : ' $var3
```

Output:

```
240
82
240+82
```

How to get the summation properly

Comment: What does this have to do with perl? What you posted isn't valid perl, it's not valid sh either. Please [edit] it to match exactly what you have.

Comment: Use `var3=\`expr $var1 + $var2\``

Comment: Looks like you need to get a tutorial on shell scripting. You don't know the very basics, and SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: I strongly suspect that your output is not the result of the script code you posted above - that script would not run for a number of different reasons, and even if it did, it's not doing what you think it is...

Comment: hi Barmer ... i am a learner in this field ... keen on learning .. at some stage you might be one too :) thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you get started, here's an **annotated, syntactically correct version of your code** that should work in all POSIX-compatible shells (e.g., `bash`):

```
#!/bin/sh

# Note that '/' (not '\') must be used as the path separator.    
cd location/address

# Capture command output using *command substitution*, `$(...)`
# Note: NO spaces around `=` are allowed.
var1=$(grep -w -c exception server.log)
var2=$(grep -w -c exception server.log.1)

# Use *arithmetic expansion*, `$((...))`, to perform integer calculations.
# Note: Inside `$((...))`, the prefix `$` is optional when referencing variables.
var3=$(( var1 + var2 ))

# Generally, it's better to *double*-quote variable references to
# make sure they're output unmodified - unquoted, they are subject to
# interpretation by the shell (so-called *shell expansions*).
echo "$var1"
echo "$var2"

# Output the result of the calculation. Note the use of just one, double-quoted
# string with an embedded variable reference.
# (By contrast, a *single*-quoted string would be used verbatim - no expansions.)
echo "sum of exceptions: $var3"
```

**General tips:**

- http://shellcheck.net is an excellent **tool for syntax-checking shell code**.
- http://explainshell.com is a great site that **explains a given command line** based on `man` pages.
- **Resources for learning `bash`**, probably the most widely used POSIX-compatible shell:

  - Introduction: http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html
  - Guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide
  - Cheat sheet: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet

Comment: I suspect the first line of that script may not be what is intended - should probably use `/` instead of backslash... Unless the subdirectory really is called `location{0x07}ddress` with the ASCII bell character in there...

Comment: @twalberg: Appreciate the pointer, thanks - fixed. (Re potential use of bell char: actually, since the string is unquoted, the shell would simply 'eat' the `\ `, resulting in `locationaddress`.)

Comment: Ah, yeah... got ahead of myself there. Forgot the C-style backslash stuff was only valid inside `$'...'`...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to perform arithmetic in UNIX shells, however, before I get into that you need to realize that unless your shell is *just different* than most shells, you need to define variables as such **without whitespace between the variable name, the `=`, or the value**: `var1='abc'`

*For this, I'm going to assume that you're* ***using bash***

```bash
echo $((( 1 + 10 )))
echo $[ 1 + 10 ]
# 11

var=0
((++var))
echo $var
# 1 

((++var))
echo $var
# 2

((--var))
echo $var
# 2

((var = 1 + 2))
echo $var
# 3

let "var = 3 + 1"  # let is another way of writing `(( ... ))`
echo $var
# 4

echo $(( 1 + 2 ))
# 3

(((var = 20 + 1)))
echo $var
# 21
```

Comment: You don't need another parenthesis inside `$(())`.

Comment: Helpful; observations in addition to @l0b0's valid point: the `((--var))` line results in `1`, not `2`. Also, you should point out that the `$[ ... ]` syntax is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`bc` command should work

```
echo "4+10" | bc
```