# AppleScript : error "sh: lame: command not found" number 127

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I am trying to create an AppleScript with commands below.  An issue I am having is there is an error at the third line.  I have no problem using the `lame` command in the terminal directly.  In addition, `lame` is not a native Mac utility; I installed it on my own. Does anybody have a solution?

```
do shell script "cd ~/Downloads"

do shell script "say -f ~/Downloads/RE.txt -o ~/Downloads/recording.aiff"

do shell script "lame -m m ~/Downloads/recording.aiff ~/Downloads/recording.mp3"

-- error "sh: lame: command not found" number 127

do shell script "rm recording.aiff RE.txt"
```

Comment: Probably a PATH problem - use the full path for lame.

Comment: @Paul Oh you are right! usr/local/bin/lame Solved!  Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome - I've converted this to an answer now in case anyone comes looking for answers to a similar problem in the future...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably a `PATH` problem - use the full path for lame, e.g.

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/lame -m m ~/Downloads/recording.aiff ~/Downloads/recording.mp3"
```

Comment: Extended question do you know Mac terminal command to rename with a form of “original file name+current_date”?

Comment: It's probably best to post that as a new question, as there may be more than one good answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I got a good solution by creating a new thread.  By the way do you know where to learn basic of shellscript programming online?

Comment: @EvanS: Look at the bottom of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23668119/45375

Answer (score 14):

To complement [Paul R's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23723223/45375):

The thing to note is that **`do shell script` - regrettably - does NOT see the same `$PATH` as shells created by `Terminal.app`** - a notable absence is `/usr/local/bin`.

On my OS X 10.9.3 system, running `do shell script "echo $PATH"` yields merely:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

There are various **ways around this**:

- **Use the full path to executables**, as in Paul's solution.
- **Manually prepend/append `/usr/local/bin`**, where many non-system executables live, to the `$PATH` - worth considering if you invoke multiple executables in a single `do shell script` command; e.g.:

```applescript
do shell script "export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:$PATH\"
 cd ~/Downloads
 say -f ~/Downloads/RE.txt -o ~/Downloads/recording.aiff
 lame -m m ~/Downloads/recording.aiff ~/Downloads/recording.mp3
 rm recording.aiff RE.txt"
```

Note how the above use a *single* `do shell script` command with *multiple* commands in a *single* string - commands can be separated by newlines or, if on the same line, with `;`.
This is more efficient than multiple invocations, though adding error handling both inside the script code and around the `do shell script` command is advisable.

- To **get the same `$PATH` that interactive shells see** (except additions made in your bash profile), you can invoke `eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s);` as the first statement in your command string.

---

Other **important considerations with `do shell script`**:

- `bash` is **invoked as `sh`**, which results in **changes in behavior**, most notably:

  - process substitution (`<(...)`) is not available
  - `echo` by default accepts no options and interprets escape sequences such as `\n`.
  - other, subtle changes in behavior; see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html
  - You could address these issues manually by prepending `shopt -uo posix; shopt -u xpg_echo;` to your command string.

- The locale is set to the **generic `"C"` locale** instead of to your system's; to fix that, manually prepend `export LANG='" & user locale of (system info) & ".UTF-8'` to your command string.

- **No startup files (profiles) are read**; this is not surprising, because the shell created is a *noninteractive* (non-login) shell, but sometimes it's handy to load one's profile by manually by prepending `. ~/.bash_profile` to the command string; note, however, that this makes your AppleScript less portable.

`do shell script` command reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2065/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling to get the path of an installed BASH command via Applescript for a long time.  Using the information here, I finally succeeded.

```
tell me to set sox_path to (do shell script "eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s); which sox")
```

Thanks.

Comment: So so much better than people hardcoding the value of PATH.

Answer (score -2):

```
Url：http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=290&package_id=309 

 ./configure

make install
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to post `lame` _installation instructions_, but the OP's problem is not that it isn't _installed_, it is that `do shell script` cannot _find_ the installed version.