# How to make "which some_command" work from in an Applescript?

Tags: bash, shell, command, sh

I am writing an Applescript that uses sox, which is not available by default in MacOS X.  I have everything working on my system, but I want the script to work for anyone else.  Because the sox command is not where Applescript can automatically locate it, my hard coded 'do shell script' string must start with "/usr/local/bin/sox" instead of just "sox."

So, I need a way to locate sox, via Applescript, on any system.  In terminal, "which sox" returns "/usr/local/bin/sox" without issue.  In Applescript, "which sox" returns "sh: which sox: command not found."  This is true for any command, not just sox.

I have tried every variation I can think of, without success.  I will list every syntax I have used and the result I get.  If anyone knows another/successful route to getting the path to sox from within an Applescript, PLEASE let me know.

Note that I have other shell commands (e.g. rm, mv, etc.) working in the script.

Lines that return "sh: which sox: command not found": (Note: I have also tried each with "which sox" replaced by which_sox, and a prior line to define which_sox as "which sox")

```
do shell script quoted form of "which sox"
do shell script (quoted form of "which sox") as text
do shell script (quoted form of "which sox") as string
tell current application to do shell script quoted form of "which sox"
tell current application to do shell script (quoted form of "which sox") as text
tell current application to do shell script (quoted form of "which sox") as string
```

Lines that return "sh: /bin/sh which sox: No such file or directory"

```
do shell script quoted form of "/bin/sh which sox"
do shell script (quoted form of "/bin/sh which sox") as text
do shell script (quoted form of "/bin/sh which sox") as string
tell current application to do shell script quoted form of "/bin/sh which sox"
tell current application to do shell script (quoted form of "/bin/sh which sox") as text
tell current application to do shell script (quoted form of "/bin/sh which sox") as string
```

(Note: I have also tried /bin/bash, /usr/local/bin/sh, and /usr/local/bin/bash both in "quotes" and as a defined which_sox variable.)

Yes, that is a LOT of methodical trial and (all) error to simply get the path of an installed command.  Please forego any answers/suggestions for methods outside of Applescript as this must run as a script from within iTunes.  Also, please attempt any proposal before posting it.  I see a lot of 'answers' on this site that get replied to as 'your suggestion didn't work.'

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution.  The following returns the path to an installed BASH command (sox in this case):

```
tell me to set sox_path to (do shell script "eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s); which sox")
```

If you want to know why this works, read [AppleScript : error "sh: lame: command not found" number 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722559)

Answer (score 0):

`quoted form of` is only for variables. Since you have a literal command to execute, you simply need

```
do shell script "which sox"
```