# Why is my shell command working at the prompt, but not as a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

New to bash scripting. I'm getting pretty familiar with shell scripting pretty well. I wrote this text transform script for a feed for a client. And extracts the url's I want, and the titles of articles. Awesome.

```
echo $(var=$(curl -L website.com/news)) | 
  grep -Po '<h3 class="article-link"><a href="\K[^<]+' <<< $var |
    result=$(sed 's/"/\n/g' | sed 's/ \//\n\//g' | sed 's/>//g') ; let this=0 ; echo "$result" | while read line ; do if ((this % 2 == 0 )) ; then echo website.com/news$line ; else echo $line ; fi ; let this+=1 ; done
```

When I try to extract it to a file and run it with bash OR sh myThing.sh, it doesn't work at all.  The only thing that echo's is 'webiste.com/news', when I try to echo $this, all I get is 1. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash   
echo $(var=$(curl -L website.com/news)) | 
  grep -Po '<h3 class="article-link"><a href="\K[^<]+' <<< $var |
    result=$(sed 's/"/\n/g' | sed 's/ \//\n\//g' | sed 's/>//g') 

 let this=0 

 echo "$result" | while read line 
 do 
    if ((this % 2 == 0 )) 
    then 
        echo website.com/news$line 
    else 
        echo $line 
    fi 
    let this+=1 
done
```

edit:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(curl -L linux.com/news) 
select=$(grep -Po '<h3 class="article-list__title"><a href="\K[^<]+' <<< $var)
result=$(sed 's/"/\n/g' | sed 's/ \//\n\//g' | sed 's/>//g') 

 let this=0 

 echo "$result" | while read line 
 do 
    if ((this % 2 == 0 )) 
    then 
        echo website.com/news$line 
    else 
        echo $line 
    fi 
    let this+=1 
done
```

Comment: When you assign a value to a variable, it doesn't print any value during the assignment operation. Therefore this line `echo $(var=$(curl -L website.com/news))` doesn't print anything. You need to replace it with the plain and simple `curl -L website.com/news 2>/dev/null`. Then it will work. Then get rid of `<<< $var`.

Comment: Look at my grep statement, I don't know how I would write that without var

Comment: Your first version doesn't need `var`. Your second version does need `var` but the `sed` command doesn't have any inputs to operate on. You need to look closely at each command and execute them one at a time on a shell to see what is wrong with each line.

Comment: @nanthil: After looking more closely at your code, I've added some more information to my answer. I've reformatted your long snippets to span multiple lines for readability - it's really worth always doing that, from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is totally wrong. You are attempting to pass thru pipes the standard output of each process when none of them ever prints anything except standard error.

```
echo $(var=$(curl -L website.com/news)) | grep -Po '<h3 class="article-link"><a href="\K[^<]+' <<< $var | result=$(sed 's/"/\n/g' | sed 's/ \//\n\//g' | sed 's/>//g')
```

I'll break down what I believe you are attempting to do.

```
echo $(var=$(curl -: website.com/news))
```

The above code will only print the standard error, which is a separate stream than standard output. The standard output is assigned to `$var`. However you are attempting to pass the standard output to the next process which is nothing but a newline at this time.

```
grep -Po '<h3 class="article-link"><a href="\K[^<]+' <<< $var
```

The here-string `<<<` takes precedence over pipe. But variable `$var` is lost as it was defined inside a sub-shell and not in the parent shell. Thanks to [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0).

The proper way to accomplish all this is to not use `$var`. All you wanted is the value stored in `$result`.

```
result=$(curl -L website.com/news | grep -Po '<h3 class="article-link"><a href="\K[^<]+'| sed 's/"/\n/g' | sed 's/ \//\n\//g' | sed 's/>//g')
```

I don't intend to optimize your script. This is more of a suggested solution. A more comprehensive answer to your question **Why is my shell command working at the prompt, but not as a bash script?** is answered by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23668119/45375).

Comment: That's exactly it. I didn't know the bit about subshells and that echo wouldn't write anything if there was a variable being set. I'm a little too used to javascript's syntax. Thanks for breaking it down for me!

Is there somewhere I can learn more about these rules in bash?

Comment: @nanthil: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23668119/45375) of mine may get you started.

Comment: @mklement0 - I totally agree that you addressed the OP's question. My answer didn't, I just gave the OP a suggested solution. I edited my answer based on your comment.

Comment: @alvits: I appreciate the update and the link to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>This answer solves the OP's *specific* problem, but to **address the question "Why is my shell command working at the prompt, but not as a bash script?" *generally***, [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) provides an excellent answer in the comments:

"You are either not running that exact command or it "works" because you have shell state that is affecting things in ways you take to be "working" and your script doesn't have that state. Try launching an entirely new shell session and see if that command, on its own, works for you there."</sup>

`echo $(var=...)` will assign a value to variable `$var`, but *will not output anything*, so the `echo` command will simply print a newline.

Furthermore, because the assignment to `$var` happens inside `$(...)` (a command substitution), it is confined to the *subshell* that the command inside the substitution ran in, so `$var` will *not* be defined in the calling shell.
(A subshell is a *child* process that contains a *duplicate* of the current shell's environment, without being able to *modify* the current shell's environment).

More generally, **you cannot meaningfully define variables *inside* a pipeline** - they will neither be visible to other pipeline segments, nor after the pipeline finishes.<sup>[1]</sup>

**The only reason your [original] command could ever have worked is if `$var` had a *preexisting value*** in your shell.
In fact, **given that you provide input to `grep` via a here-string (`<<<`), the first segment of your pipeline (`echo ...`) is entirely *ignored*.**

To pass the output of `curl` through the pipeline to `grep` and then to `sed`, **no intermediate variables are needed at all.**
Furthermore, your `sed` command is lacking *input*: you probably meant to feed it `$var` in your first attempt, and `$select` in the 2nd (your 2nd attempt came close to a correct solution).

What you were probably ultimately looking for:

```
result=$(curl -L website.com/news | 
  grep -Po '<h3 class="article-link"><a href="\K[^<]+' |
    sed 's/"/\n/g' | sed 's/ \//\n\//g' | sed 's/>//g')

# ... processing of "$result"
```

Some additional notes:

- You could combine the 3 `sed` calls into a single one.
- You could feed the pipeline output directly into your `while` loop, without the need for intermediate variable `$result`.
- You should generally *double-quote* variable references (e.g., use `"$line"` instead of `$line` to protect them from interpretation by the shell (word-splitting, globbing).
- `let this+=1` is better expressed as `(( ++this ))` in modern Bash.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23668119/45375) of mine contains links to resources for learning about `bash`.

---

<sup>[1] All commands involved in a *pipeline* by default run in a *subshell* in `bash`, so they all see *copies* of the *parent* shell's variables. Bash 4.2+ offers the `lastpipe` option (off by default) to allow you to create variables in the *current* shell instead of in a *subshell*, by running the *last* pipeline segment (only) in the current shell instead of in a subshell, to facilitate scenarios such as `... | while read -r line ...` and have `$line` continue to exist after the pipeline finishes.

Note that this still doesn't enable defining a variable in an earlier pipeline segment in the hopes that a later segment will see it - this can *never* work, because the commands that make up a pipeline are launched *at the same time*, and it is only through coordination of the input and output streams that effective left-to-right processing happens.</sup>

Comment: Then why does it do what I expect in the shell?

Comment: @nanthil It doesn't. You are mistaken. You are either not running that exact command or it "works" because you have shell state that is affecting things in ways you take to be "working" and your script doesn't have that state. Try launching an entirely new shell session and see if that command, on its own, works for you there.

Comment: i have updated the original post with my current iteration, still having issues.